# JDBC result set retrieve LocalDateTime

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, java-time

I run a simple query to retrieve a row from a MySQL database.
I get `ResultSet` and I need to retrieve a LocalDateTime object from it.
My DB table.

```
CREATE TABLE `some_entity` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to retrieve some entity by id.

```
String SELECT = "SELECT ID, TITLE, TEXT, CREATED_DATE_TIME FROM some_entity WHERE some_entity.id = ?";
PreparedStatement selectPreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT);
try {
    selectPreparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
    ResultSet resultSet = selectPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
    if (resultSet.next()) {
        Long foundId = resultSet.getLong(1);
        String title = resultSet.getString(2);
        String text = resultSet.getString(3);
        LocalDateTime createdDateTime = null;// How do I retrieve it???
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to retrieve some entity by id.", e);
}
```

Comment: this might help [Parse DateTime to LocalDateTime from resulset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773390/getting-the-date-from-a-resultset-for-use-with-java-time-classes)

Comment: Yes, I see. 1) Retrieve timestamp from the resultSet, 2) convert it into LocalDateTime...

Comment: If the JDBC driver is reasonably current and has been updated to work with Java 8 then you should be able to use `resultSet.getObject(4, LocalDateTime.class)`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try retrieving this as [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) and then converting to [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) using [`Timestamp.toLocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toLocalDateTime--):

```
LocalDateTime createdDateTime = resultSet.getTimestamp(4).toLocalDateTime()
```

*EDIT*: As [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson) pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632735/jdbc-result-set-retrieve-localdatetime#comment90232701_51632735), there's an even better solution when working with a recent enough JDBC driver:

> `resultSet.getObject(4, LocalDateTime.class)`

This skips creating a redundant `java.sql.Timestamp` instance.

Comment: Even if I use DateTime for MySQL, I should call `getTimestamp()`? Not `getDate()`?

Comment: [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) has no time component: "To conform with the definition of SQL `DATE`, the millisecond values wrapped by a `java.sql.Date` instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated." I do not guaratee that `java.sql.Timestamp` will work, though, but it seems to be the only type that represents date-time in `java.sql` package.

Comment: +1 for the edit. It also avoids the problem of Timestamp potentially corrupting certain date/time values, e.g., `2018-03-11 02:00:00` (2 AM) in `America/Toronto` will magically be changed to 3 AM.

Comment: `resultSet.getObject(4, LocalDateTime.class)` using postgres and latest jdbc lib didn't work for me.  `resultSet.getTimestamp(4).toLocalDateTime()` did work

Comment: I tried this technique recently.  However, even though the above code should work, there's a MySQL driver bug that incorrectly applies a timezone offset to the `LocalDateTime` value.  This bug is still open as of MySQL Connector Java version 8.0.19.  Reference: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93444