# How to work with Oracle's TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE Datatype in Java

Tags: java, oracle

The issue has in two parts.

1. I want to know what is the best way to access the Oracle `TIMESTAMP` WITH `TIMEZONE` column in an entity class. I've checked around and found that this DB data type maps to `TimeStamp` datatype in Java but this doesn't store timezone information.
2. **Issue** is the DB is not saving data as `2017-08-10 10:30:20.15 -07:00` which is how I want it saved, it is converting it to the server's timezone and saving the value. Do I have to turn off some settings to get the DB to work the way I want?

So, My initial idea was to use the `ZonedDateTime` data type since it can capture the date properly in the format which I want, which is `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` ( aka `yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss TZM:TZ`). But this doesn't map to the DB data type and I lose Timezone info when converting to some other datatype.

Comment: you can use SimpleDateFormater in java to format your output from database as you like. And in database you can store your date as string which will be exactly what you want and how you want. And also you can find very nice article from oracle https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG238 about how to use TIMESTAMP if you actually need to use TIMESTAMP in database

Comment: OT: there were written several articles about that. Even on Java side it is complicated. Moreover using this datatype might save few performance implications.IMHO: if possible try to avoid using this type unless really necessary

Comment: `OffsetDateTime` should work according to the JDBC 4.2 spec. Haven’t tried it myself, though. See for example [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907501/5772882).