# Java cannot parse string to date

Tags: java, date

I have a string with date, that i want to convert to Date/LocalDateTime/Instant and to save it in PostgreSQL in future. How can I do it? Cases that i've tried:

```
String actualDate = "05-01-2020 03:07";
String pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(actualDate, formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

retunrs this value: `2020-01-05T03:07`,

```
String actualDate = "05-01-2020 03:07";
String pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
Date localDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(actualDate);
System.out.println(localDateTime);
```

returns
`Sun Jul 05 03:00:00 MSK 2020`

Comment: Do not longer use Date and SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: It is not really clear what your Problem is.

Comment: Problem is that string isn't saved in format that i need

Comment: Ist will be saved as date type it has no format. What you See is the result of a toString function.

Comment: Is that means that i have to save in any format and parse after getting from database?

Comment: You can use java.sql.Timestamp. Use `Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime)` for conversion

Comment: @Alexey yes because or saves a date not a Formated string.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead depending on the type in your database use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: What is the datatype in SQL? And which database engine are you using? When transferring a date-time object like `LocalDateTime` to and from your database, don’t worry about the format, your database driver will take care of that.

Comment: @AbinashGhosh That wold have been a good suggestion some years back. However since JDBC 4.2 we have nothing to use the poorly designed and long outdated `java.sql.Timestamp` for. We can save `LocalDateTime` and other modern types directly to the database. See for example [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907501/5772882).

Answer (score 1):

## `java.util.Date::toString` tells a lie

The `Date` class represents a moment in UTC, having an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

The `toString` method unfortunately applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the text. This creates the illusion of that zone being a part of that object.

**Never use `java.util.Date`.**

## ISO 8601

Educate the publisher of your input data about the date-time formats defined in the ISO 8601 standard. These formats are designed for data exchange, easy to parse by machine, and easy to read by humans across cultures.

## Database

Your particular input lacks a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it should be stored in a column of a type akin to the standard SQL type of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` (notice *WITHOUT*, not *WITH*). Postgres offers that type by that name.

Use a JDBC driver that complies with JDBC 4.2 or later. That standard requires support for exchanging date-time values using the modern *java.time* classes.

Parse input as shown in your Question.

```
String input = "05-01-2020 03:07";
String pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( pattern ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , formatter ) ;
```

Save to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieve.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String actualDate = "05-01-2020 03:07";

String pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";

Date localDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(actualDate);

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(localDateTime));
```

Output : `05-01-2020 03:07`

Hope this will work.

Comment: These terrible date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.