# Setting a timestamp object + 1 hour

Tags: java, syntax, timestamp

I need help setting a TimeStamp object + 1 hour. Apparently my system retrives the timestamp data -1 hour from original sql data.

I want to know if there is a quick way in Java to add 1 hour manually. Im thinking in the lines of what my code example below shows.

```
public boolean chooseBreak(String time, int id) throws IllegalArgumentException 
{

   Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(time);

   ts.setTime(+ 1);
```

Comment: I suggest not implementing a quick fix for a time zone related issue. Find out why exactly you're 1 hour off and fix the problem thoroughly. You can't `+1` all of your timestamps all the time

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead if you are having a `timestamp with time zone` in SQL, retrieve an `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). If the datatype in SQL is `datetime` or `timestamp` without time zone, use `LocalDateTime`. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907501/5772882).

Comment: It’s most certainly a timezone issue. From the information in the question we cannot know the details, but you should solve the root cause of non-matching time zones, not apply a patch of adding an hour.