# How can I take into account the TimeZone of java.sql.Date when I read it from database?

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc

My application reads java.sql.Date from database witch contains these dates in America/New_York time zone (-4 UTC). After a fetching of data Hibernate creates objects java.sql.Date and represents them in my local time zone. So, I need to convert date from database in UTC directly. How can I do that?

I need something like this

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(((java.sql.Date) value).getTime()).atOffset(offset);
```

But **offset** doesn't do what I want. For example:

time in database: 01-02-2020 22:00 (in America/New_York -> it's UTC-4 and I need to add extra 4 hours)

time in my application: 01-02-2020 22:00 +4 (because my time zone is UTC+4). When I set ZoneOffset.UTC

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(((java.sql.Date) value).getTime()).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

it removes 4 hours ans toString() result = 01-02-2020T16:00Z

How can I add 4 hour to date (java.sql.Date) in database so that it would be **02-02-2020 02:00** UTC ?

Comment: What is the datatype in the database? And which database engine, by the way? I’m confused that you seem to have a time of day in a `java.sql.Date` — it *pretends* to be a date without time of day (but I know, it’s got millisecond precision inside of it).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Date` if there’s any way you can avoid it. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead retrieve for example a `LocalDate` from your database, from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Related and potentially helpful: [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2)

Comment: Which value does `((java.sql.Date) value).getTime()` return in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a point in time with a time zone such as 2020-02-01T22:00-04:00[America/New_York], do not use `java.sql.Date`. For two reasons:

1. `java.sql.Date` is a poorly designed class, a true hack, indeed, on top if the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class. Fortunately both `Date` classes are also long outdated.
2. `java.sql.Date` was designed for a date without time of day.

Instead:

- In your SQL database use `timestamp with time zone` and store times consistently in UTC. So the time stored in your database should be 2020-02-02T02:00Z (Z for UTC).
- In Java retrieve your time into an `OffsetDateTime` (since JDBC 4.2 we can do that, bypassing `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` completely). Then if needed convert to a `ZonedDateTime` in your time zone. Use a proper time zone ID in the *region/city* format (not just what you think the UTC offset is).

For a demonstration:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tbilisi");

    OffsetDateTime dateTimeFromDatabase
            = OffsetDateTime.of(2020, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    ZonedDateTime dateTimeInYourTimeZone
            = dateTimeFromDatabase.atZoneSameInstant(zone);
    System.out.println(dateTimeInYourTimeZone);
```

Output:

> 2020-02-02T06:00+04:00[Asia/Tbilisi]

Edit 1: You said:

> I understand that this is bad to use outdated java.sql.Date, but I
>   have no choice. "java.sql.Date was designed for a date without time of
>   day." - but I thought I can anyway get time of day by calling
>   (java.sql.Date) value).getTime() (because it returns timestamp)

From the documentation:

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values
>   wrapped by a `java.sql.Date` instance must be 'normalized' by setting
>   the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the
>   particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

So it seems to me that you’re breaking the contract. What the consequences are, I don’t know. They probably depend on your JDBC driver. That is, behaviour might change with the next version of that JDBC driver.

Edit 2: I took a closer look at your data. I agree with you that they are wrong; but the problem is not in the code you have presented, it’s in the `java.sql.Date` object that you seem to have received somehow.

For my investigation I did:

```
    // time in database: 01-02-2020 22:00
    // (in America/New_York -> it's UTC-4 and I need to add extra 4 hours)
    ZonedDateTime dateTimeInDatebase = ZonedDateTime
            .of(2020, 2, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
    System.out.println("In database:     " + dateTimeInDatebase);
    long correctEpochMillis = dateTimeInDatebase.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println("Correct millis:  " + correctEpochMillis);

    // toString() result = 01-02-2020T16:00Z
    OffsetDateTime observedDateTime
            = OffsetDateTime.of(2020, 2, 1, 16, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    long observedEpochMilli = observedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println("Observed millis: " + observedEpochMilli);

    Duration error = Duration.between(dateTimeInDatebase, observedDateTime);
    System.out.println("Error:           " + error);
```

The output is:

> ```
> In database:     2020-02-01T22:00-05:00[America/New_York]
> Correct millis:  1580612400000
> Observed millis: 1580572800000
> Error:           PT-11H
> ```

Observations:

1. The UTC offset in New York in February is not -04:00 but -05:00 (-04:00 is the correct offset during summer time/DST).
2. The millisecond value that you have retrieved from your `java.sql.Date` does not denote the point in time that it should. There is nothing in your code that changes the point in time. So you are not only getting an incorrect type, you are also getting an incorrect value.
3. Read the error printed in the last output line as a period of time of minus 11 hours. The millisecond value in your `java.sql.Date` is 11 hours too early.

You have yourself explained some of the discrepancy with the time zone difference, and I believe that this is true. We have not yet verified that this is the whole story. So I also cannot tell you what the solution is. Other than filing a ticket to the provider of your incorrect type and value so you get correct data instead. A possible hack is to add 11 hours, of course, but whether you then should add only 10 hours in the summer time part of the year — I am not the correct person to ask.

Edit 3:

> I just came up with an idea to fix twice value of timestamp. Like the
>   first time - add offset of local zone (fix the influence of jdbc
>   driver), and the second - handle offset of dates stored in database.

We can do that if we want:

```
    Instant observedResult = Instant.parse("2020-02-01T16:00:00Z");
    Object receivedValue = new java.sql.Date(observedResult.toEpochMilli());

    long receivedEpochMillis = ((java.sql.Date) receivedValue).getTime();
    ZonedDateTime adjustedDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(receivedEpochMillis)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));

    System.out.println(adjustedDateTime);
```

Output when run in Asia/Tbilisi time zone (so this is what `ZoneId.systemDefault()` returned; it’s at offset +04:00 all year):

> 2020-02-01T20:00-05:00[America/New_York]

It brings us closer to what you say was in the database, but it’s still a couple of hours too early. I am sorry.

### Links

- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907501/5772882) to a related question: Getting the date from a ResultSet for use with java.time classes
- [Documentation of `java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for answer, I understand that this is bad to use outdated java.sql.Date, but I have no choice.

"java.sql.Date was designed for a date without time of day." - but I thought I can anyway get time of day by calling (java.sql.Date) value).getTime() (because it returns timestamp)

Comment: I don’t know about that. I have added a paragraph with my doubts and reservations at the bottom of the answer. @vulpes

Comment: thank for your time. I also think, that there is no here a proper solution. I just came up with an idea to fix twice value of timestamp. Like the first time - add offset of local zone (fix the influence of jdbc driver), and the second - handle offset of dates stored in database. Anyway thanks for your attention and willingness to help!

Comment: I had the same idea. See my edit 3. I suggest that you wait until after the weekend before deciding whether you want to accept this answer. Other answers may come in the meantime, and questions without an accepted answer tend to get more attention, so your chances are greater that way.

Comment: Thanks one more time) I've marked your answer as solution anyway