# Java - Convert a given DateTime in String to local timezone

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone

I am reading a timestamp from a database as a string value, 
say:

> 2020-04-30T09:59:00.272-05:00

.
Now i have to compare this with current timestamp in local timezone(System timezone)

What i have tried so Far:

`ZonedDateTime result = ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-04-30T09:59:00.272-05:00");
 System.out.println("Given         : "+result);
 System.out.println("Given In Local: "+result.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.systemDefault()));`

OutPut: 

`Given         : 2020-04-30T09:59:00.272-05:00
Given In Local: 2020-04-30T09:59:00.272-05:00[America/Chicago]`

My Desired output is **"2020-04-30T14:59:00.272"**

Comment: In your desired output you have thrown away the offset information ( `-05:00`). For a correct comparison don’t do that. Do you want to convert to UTC? Why? Asking because I see no reason to, you can compare `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` object across different time zones or offsets. If you do need to, us `ZoneOffset.UTC`. And mentioning `OffsetDateTime` because it seems a better fit for your database value than `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the given date string as an `OffsetDateTime`, then change its offset and convert it to `LocalDateTime` as follows

````
    final String dateString = "2020-04-30T09:59:00.272-05:00";
    final ZonedDateTime result = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println("Given         : " + result);
    final LocalDateTime localDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString)
        .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"))
        .toLocalDateTime();
    System.out.println("Given In Local: " + localDateTime);```
````

prints

```
Given         : 2020-04-30T09:59:00.272-05:00
Given In Local: 2020-04-30T16:59:00.272
```

Besides, you could also parse it to `ZonedDateTime` and then change the time zone, e.g.

```
final LocalDateTime result = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString)
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"))
        .toLocalDateTime();
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried your suggestion, but it is printing the same value i.e, "2020-04-30T09:59:00.272"

Comment: Can you try to replace `ZoneId.systemDefault()` with the `ZoneId` you want to be the time converted to?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following should fulfil your purpose.

```
    String dateTimeString = "2020-04-30T09:59:00.272-05:00";
    OffsetDateTime databaseDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeString );
    OffsetDateTime currentDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    if (databaseDateTime.isAfter(currentDateTime)) {
        System.out.println("" + databaseDateTime + " is after " + currentDateTime);
    } else {
        System.out.println("" + databaseDateTime + " is before or equal to " + currentDateTime);
    }
```

Output when I ran the code just now in my time zone (Europe/Copenhagen):

> 2020-04-30T09:59:00.272-05:00 is after 2020-04-26T21:48:36.331752+02:00

Since your string from the database contains a UTC offset (`-05:00`) and no time zone (like America/New_York), I found it more appropriate to parse into an `OffsetDateTime`. `ZonedDateTime` would be overkill. For the local time I am passing `ZoneId.systemDefault()` to the `now` method of `OffsetDateTime`. Comparing the two `OffsetDateTime` objects with `isAfter()` works nicely even if the offsets are different, this is taken into account. There are also methods `isBefore` and `isEqual` for comparison.

Stepping a step back, in most setups you should not be getting the date and time as a string from your database. Your JDBC 4.2 driver or your modern JPA implementation such as Hibernate 5 will be happy to fetch an `OffsetDateTime` object from the database for you. See for example [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907501/5772882).

Comment: Thanks @Ole, I think there is some problem with the way we storing the dateTIme in the db. But both the answers should solve my problem.