# Convert String to Date with Milliseconds

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, java.util.date

I know that there many subject of how to convert from String to Date, I'm using 'SimpleDateFormat' and i have a string that contains (Year, Month, Day , Hour, Minute, second, Milliseconds) but when I'm using the 'SimpleDateFormat' the Milliseconds is not set
here the code and the output:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

String strDate = "2020-08-27T10:06:07.413";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date dateFormatter = formatter.parse(strDate);

System.out.println(dateFormatter);
```

Output:

```
Thu Aug 27 10:06:07 WAT 2020
```

I want the result in type Date

Comment: Use `java.time` and stop using `java.util.Date` as well as `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`... Is your system time zone West Africa Time?

Comment: I want Date as type of result, I've edited the question (adding the imports), I don't know how to use java.time in this type of example

Comment: How do you output the `Date`? Can you show us that line of code?

Comment: I using Sout(), , I've edited the question (adding the sout)

Comment: To see the millis in output you need to print the parsed date using format, not just `System.out.println(dateFormatter);`  Default format in `Date.toString` is not set up to display millis.  And yes, `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormatter` are outdated for a long time and their use is severely discouraged.  Please use Java 8 Date-Time API defined in `java.time` package.

Comment: Related and probably helpful: (1) [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2) (2) [Getting the date from a ResultSet for use with java.time classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773390/getting-the-date-from-a-resultset-for-use-with-java-time-classes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Date class stores the time as milliseconds, and if you look into your date object you will see that it actually has a time of 1598515567413 milliseconds.

You are fooled by the System.out.println() which uses Date's toString() method. This method is using the "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" format to display the date and simply omits all milliseconds.

If you use your formatter, which has milliseconds in its format string, you will see that the milliseconds are correct:

```
System.out.println(formatter.format(dateFormatter));
```

outputs 2020-08-27T10:06:07.413

Comment: Yes that worked, but is there any solution to wiew it in type Date an not String

Comment: No, `Date` has no configurable internal format. The old Date often comes with the usage of the (old) `Calendar`. That is a more accessible class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
String strDate = "2020-08-27T10:06:07.413"

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
DateTime datetimeDF = formatter.parseDateTime(strDate);
String text = formatter.print(datetimeDF);

System.out.println(text);
```

Or you can use `java.time`:

```
String strDate = "2020-08-27T10:06:07.413"
LocalDateTime ldate = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
```

and use the object `ldate` as you want.

Comment: I want to view the date in Date format and not String with Milliseconds

Comment: to view it where? in the console? in the `System.out.println()` ?

Comment: Yes, there is no goal to convert it than

Answer (score 2):

### Update (based on OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63631068/convert-string-to-date-with-milliseconds/63632040#comment112522325_63632040)):

**You have mentioned**: Thanks that was realy heplful I've allready tried the java.util but i could not set the date in the database using LocalDateTime that's why I'm using Date

You've to use `PreparedStatement#setObject` to set `LocalDate` into the database table e.g.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (columnfoo) VALUES (?)");
st.setObject(1, localDate);
st.executeUpdate(); 
st.close();
```

### Original answer:

Given below is the `toString` implementation of `java.util.Date`:

```
public String toString() {
    // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
    BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
    int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
    if (index == BaseCalendar.SUNDAY) {
        index = 8;
    }
    convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[index]).append(' ');                        // EEE
    convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[date.getMonth() - 1 + 2 + 7]).append(' ');  // MMM
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getDayOfMonth(), 2).append(' '); // dd

    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getHours(), 2).append(':');   // HH
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getMinutes(), 2).append(':'); // mm
    CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getSeconds(), 2).append(' '); // ss
    TimeZone zi = date.getZone();
    if (zi != null) {
        sb.append(zi.getDisplayName(date.isDaylightTime(), TimeZone.SHORT, Locale.US)); // zzz
    } else {
        sb.append("GMT");
    }
    sb.append(' ').append(date.getYear());  // yyyy
    return sb.toString();
}
```

As you can see in this implementation, it doesn't include `milliseconds` and therefore if you print `date` as in the following code, you will get what the `Date#toString` returns and thus, you won't see `milliseconds` in the output.

```
String strDate = "2020-08-27T10:06:07.413";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date= formatter.parse(strDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

I assume that you already know that `System.out.println(obj)` prints the string returned by `obj.toString()`.

### How can you get output in a custom format?

You have two options:

1. Recommended option: Use a date-time formatter e.g. `SimpleDateFormat` as shown below:

   ```
   String strDate = "2020-08-27T10:06:07.413";
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
   Date date = formatter.parse(strDate);
   System.out.println(date);

   String dateStr = formatter.format(date);
   System.out.println(dateStr);
   ```
2. Override `toString` implementation of `Date` by creating a custom class by extending `java.util.Date`. Although it's an option, I never recommend this to do.

### Finally, a piece of advice:

**Stop** using the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat`. Switch to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (`java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Thanks that was realy heplful I've allready tried the java.util but i could not set the date in the database using LocalDateTime that's why I'm using Date

Comment: @MohamedDrira - You are most welcome. I've added an update to help you with setting `LocalDate` into the database.

Comment: This is the most modern and helpful answer. Highly recommended.