# Converting "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" and "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSX" to one common Timestamp for a SQL table

Tags: sql, scala, datetime, timestamp

I have two different formats for data and I am trying to have a common format.

**Format A**

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"`

Sample time:
`2020-09-10T22:40:58.807+00:00`

**Format B**

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSX"`

Sample time:
`2020-07-23T02:46:04.0978382Z`

I am trying to merge them into one common format and eventually use them for a SQL Dataframe with type Timestamp. I have been using SimpleDateFormat for format A, and for Format B I cannot parse with SimpleDateFormat as it doesn't support Nanoseconds, so instead have been using

```
val inFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timestampFormat)
val localDatetime = LocalDateTime.parse(timestampString, inFormat)
Timestamp.valueOf(localDatetime) // converting Datetime to timestamp
```

After using the above my Format B sample time is 2020-07-23 02:46:04.0978382 While format A using SimpleDateFormat is 2020-09-10 22:40:58.807

How can I create a common format for both A and B to be later used into a SQL table? My goal is for whats in format A matches what is in format B(granularity too).

Something that I am trying is using OffsetDateTime to convert both formats. With OffSetDateTime I will

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime
val odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(2020-07-23T02:46:04.0978382Z)
println(odt)
```

In this case, seems like I would truncate offsetDatetime? Is this a good approach?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need a common format, you need to try to parse both. You can try to parse it and catch an exception, or find Scala lib that will produce an option.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead pass either an `OffsetDateTime`, an `Instant` or a `LocalDateTime` to your SQL database. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907501/5772882).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven’t got two different formats. What you call format A and format B are both variants of ISO 8601 format, the international standard. `OffsetDateTime` parses the most common ISO 8601 variants as its default, that is, without any explicit formatter. Also both of your variants.

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTimeA = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-09-10T22:40:58.807+00:00");
    System.out.println(dateTimeA);
    OffsetDateTime dateTimeB = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-07-23T02:46:04.0978382Z");
    System.out.println(dateTimeB);
```

Output:

> ```
> 2020-09-10T22:40:58.807Z
> 2020-07-23T02:46:04.097838200Z
> ```

You also notice that no values have been truncated.

You probably don’t need to convert to a `java.sql.Timestamp`. That’s good because the `Timestamp` class is a hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class, and both those classes are long outdated. Assuming that you need a `timestamp with time zone` in SQL (recommended for timestamps), since JDBC 4.2 pass your `OffsetDateTime` to SQL. An example:

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTimeA = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-09-10T22:40:58.807+00:00");
    
    PreparedStatement insertStmt = yourDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(
            "insert into your_table(your_timestamp_with_time_zone_column) values (?)");
    insertStmt.setObject(1, dateTimeA);
    int rowsInserted = insertStmt.executeUpdate();
```

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [My answer to a related question: Getting the date from a ResultSet for use with java.time classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907501/5772882)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a "common" format.

You have 2 options:

1. You can detect with regex what format your current input has.

Like:

```
def parse(inputString: String): Timestamp {
  if(isFormatA(inputString))
    parseFormatA(inputString)
  else 
    parseFromatB(inputString)
}
```

You can improve it with regex pattern matching.

2. You can sequentially try both formats with exception handling or library that will return option.

Like:

```
def parse(inputString: String): Timestamp {
  Try(parseFormatA(inputString))
    .orElse(Try(parseFormatB(inputString)))
    .get
}
```