# Convert date time in java

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime, datetime-format

Through PostgreSQL I received date-time like this format

```
2022-11-28 23:36:43.712
```

Anyone know how to convert this to following format in Java

```
Mon Nov 28 20:51:58 IST 2022
```

or its ok to convert Mon Nov 28 20:51:58 IST 2022 to 2022-11-28 23:36:43.712 format.

Comment: Retrieve it as a LocalDateTime, then use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format it as a string

Comment: Your target type is `ZonedDateTime`

Comment: What *exactly* is the data type of your column?

Comment: “reserved”?    Is that a typo?

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name probably already meant to say, do not retrieve your date and time as a string from your database. Retrieve a `LocalDateTime`. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773390/getting-the-date-from-a-resultset-for-use-with-java-time-classes).

Comment: In which time zone is the value in the database? And in which time zone do you want the output?

Comment: `retrievedLocalDateTime .atZone(dbZone) .withZoneSameInstant(userZone) .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d H:mm:ss.SSS zzz u", Locale.ENGLISH))` where `dbZone` and `userZone` are appropriate `ZoneId` or `ZoneOffset` objects. If the former is UTC and the latter Asia/Tel_Aviv, the result is `Tue Nov 29 1:36:43.712 IST 2022`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterIn = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"); 
ZonedDateTime yourDate = ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-11-28 23:36:43.712", formatterIn.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")));

DateTimeFormatter formatterOut = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"); 
String yourDateFormatted = formatterOut.format(yourDate);

System.out.println(yourDateFormatted);
```

And if you are in India you can take ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta")